# Porque esta chamada é inserida automaticamente no corpo do HTML?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-material, momentjs

Em um app estou usando as bibliotecas em Javascript: jQuery, Angular, Angular Material e Moment. Totalizando tenho as seguintes chamadas em meu arquivo:

```
<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="vendor/angular/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular/angular-animate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular/angular-aria.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular/angular-cookies.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular/angular-messages.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular/angular-route.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular/angular-sanitize.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular/angular-base64.min.js" type="text/javascript"</script>
<script src="vendor/angular/re-tree.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular/ng-device-detector.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular/angular-mask.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="vendor/moment/moment.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="vendor/moment/moment-with-locales.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- angular-material -->
<script src="vendor/angular-material/angular-material.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Teoricamente são todas bibliotecas confiáveis, porém ao rodar minha aplicação é inserido misteriosamente esta chamada ao corpo do HTML.

```
<script src="//s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/forton/live_http_headers.js"></script>
```

Já tentei retirar a maioria das bibliotecas mantendo apenas o necessário, também pesquisei a url requisitada nos arquivos das bibliotecas, porém a mesma não é encontrada. Outro detalhe é que ao requisitar esta informação o acesso é bloqueado.

- Contudo, esta url teria alguma utilidade?
- Pode ser um risco ao projeto?
- Alguma das bibliotecas citada usa estes recursos?

Comment: Você estaria utilizando o Firefox? Acredito que esta deve ser uma dependência carregada automaticamente via algum complemento de seu browser. Tente abrir com outro navegador, e veja se ainda permanece este javascript.

Comment: As vezes, dentro de alguma dessas bibliotecas, pode conter uma dependência, e esta dependência pode estar sendo chamada em um auto create element, exemplo: `(function(a,b,c,d) {
 
    a = s.createElement(o),
        m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
    a.async = 1;
    a.src = g;
    m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
})(window, document, 'script', '//script.js', 'exec');` Porém, aparentemente, você está com um malware no seu navegador, [veja aqui](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-link43wow-com-s3-website-eu-central-1-amazonaws-com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse script inserido em tempo de execução, é feito pela extensão do Chrome:

> Live HTTP Headers

[image: **Extensão do Chrome - Live Http Headers**]

Mais informações sobre essa extensão você pode encontrar no link abaixo:

https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/5arx3l/live_http_headers_extension_hijacked/